# difference between <?php echo $pno ?> and <?=$pno?>

Tags: php, echo, php-shorttags

Please help me out regarding a small line of code. I want to get the value in the textbox.

Sometimes this line works:

`<td width="292" bgcolor="#EDEFF4"><input name="pno" type="text" id="pno" value="<?php echo $pno?>"/></td>`

and sometimes this line works:

`<td width="292" bgcolor="#EDEFF4"><input name="pno" type="text" id="pno" value="<?=$pno?>"/></td>`

So whats the difference between

```
<?php echo $pno ?>
```

and

```
<?=$pno?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're both the same, the latter is just a shorthand.
The shorthand does require your PHP settings to allow it, though.

Answer (score 5):

There is none.

```
<?= 'foo' ?>
```

translates to

```
<?php echo 'foo' ?>
```

But be aware:

```
<?= 'foo' ?>
```

Is a short tag syntax which can be disabled in the php.ini so sometimes you can't rely on it if the server administrator disabled it

(More information on using shorttags [Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use))

Answer (score 3):

**You should use**

```
<?php echo $pno; ?>
```

Both options are supposed to give the same result. However, if you would like to use the latter option, your webserver must have the option `short_open_tag` turned on. It is a compatibility issue.

Comment: While I do agree with you your answer doesn't actually answer the OP's question